# String input not working correctly using Scanner class

Tags: java, string

I want to get 3 strings from console and followed print the values, my problem is to get 3 input from user using for loop , but only 2 input values are received and printed here is my code.

```
int rockSize=sc.nextInt();
String[] rock=new String[rockSize];
for(int i=0;i<rock.length;i++)
rock[i]=sc.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to swallow up the `ENTER` that you push after inputting your numeric value.

e.g.

```
int rockSize=sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();                         // add this
String[] rock=new String[rockSize];
for(int i=0;i<rock.length;i++)
rock[i]=sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: thank you , but why we need to put this extra line? can u plz explain?

Comment: @Mareeswaran - because `nextInt()` leaves behind a new-line character (when you press "enter"). `nextLine()` consumes it